# Pendulum-like effect

Tags: applied-mechanics

In modeling a wing with the finite element method, I am asked to consider an engine (approximated as a lumped force and moment) and it's mass, inertia, prestress and gravity contributions.

So the engine contribution (in terms of mass and inertia) to the Virtual Work is:

$$\delta \mathcal{W}_{engine} = - \delta s^{T} M \ddot{s} - \delta \theta^{T} J \ddot{\theta}$$

where $s$ is the displacement of the engine.

How should I add the prestress and the pendulum-like contribution?

Comment: That would depend on your model. Does your model has rotational degrees of freedom?

Comment: yes, the wind can rotate and bend.

Comment: Not the whole thing. Each single node of your model.